# How can I 'push' and 'pop' from a queue of classes?

Tags: c++, class, queue, simulation

I am writing a program that is a simulation of service jobs by the CPU of a mulit-user computer. I've defined a class called `job` and I have created two queues of that type, one is `waitQueue` and the other one is `CPUqueue`. I'm trying to populate the `CPUqueue` with the data from the `waitQueue` by popping it from the `waitQueue` and pushing it into the `CPUqueue` -- that is the goal, however. I cannot seem to write this portion without errors saying `error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘waitQueue’, which is of non-class type ‘std::queue<job> [10]’` (likewise for the other function calls as well. Please help..!

Here is the main.cpp file that I have been working on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <queue>
#include "job.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int second = 0, jobsCompleted = 0, jobsToComplete = 0, probUser = 0, probability;
  long id;
  jobType_t job_type;
  int inWQ, outWQ, inCPUQ, outCPUQ, required, given, jobTypeInt;
  queue<job> CPUqueue[10], waitQueue[10];

  srand(time(NULL));

  cout << "Enter how many jobs need to be completed: ";
  cin >> jobsToComplete;
  cout << endl <<  "Enter the probability that a new job is created: ";
  cin >> probUser;
  cout << endl;

  while(jobsCompleted < jobsToComplete)
    {
      second++;
      probability = rand() % 100 + 1;

      if(probability > probUser)
    {
      cout << "Enter new JOB ID: ";
      cin >> id;
      jobTypeInt = rand() % 1 + 1;
      if(jobTypeInt = 1) job_type = IO_bound;
      else job_type = CPU_bound;
      required = rand() % 10;
      inWQ = second;
      job *newJob = new job(id, job_type, inWQ, outWQ, inCPUQ, outCPUQ, required, given); 
      waitQueue.push(newJob);
    }
      while(!CPUqueue.isFull())
    {
      waitQueue.back();
      job *temp = waitQueue.pop();

      CPUqueue.push(temp);
    }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
queue<job> CPUqueue[10], waitQueue[10];
```

This creates two arrays of 10 queues. It's probably not what you want.

Try :

```
queue<job> CPUqueue, waitQueue;
```

Comment: and then `CPUqueue.size(10);
waitQueue.size(10);`

Comment: @VincentGiuliana: The queue will dynamically size as required.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of queues, rather than a queue and push does not work on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @otibom's answer:

```
non-class type ‘std::queue<job> [10]’
```

means just that: `waitQueue` is declared as an array.  The objects in the array are `queue`s, but the veriable isn't.